# How to finish all Activities except Main Activity and call another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am implementing Drawer Navigation in my Application. On click of each item of drawer menu list i am  calling another Activity and this Drawer Navigation is implemented in every activity.

Now i want to clear BackStack while calling an activity on each item click, so if i press back button then there should not be the previous activity from which user jumped to the current activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do like this-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i think this code will call Main Activity and will remove all other activities.. but i don't want to go to Main Activity. i actually want to start another Activity and want my application's back stack to be like Main Activity at bottom and then the activity i started at the top.
e.g : Main Activity -> Activity X

Comment: The practical reason that why you want to do so in unclear. We keep activity in backstack to go back to it. So it is as easy as `go to back when you need`. And so is the above code. However, you can add `android:noHistory="true"` to the activity definition of B and C. They will not get added to the backstack.

Comment: Actually as per application requirement, i need to get back to main  activity from each activity, and if i keep adding activities to back stack then application crashes with the error "Out of memory on a 3330016-byte allocation".

Comment: You don't need to add any activity. So it is simple. From each activity when you click back then just write the above code to return to the `MainActivity`.

Comment: and what if i want to clear complete back stack while calling a new activity which is not in back stack already ?

Comment: Then just call `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This will clear all the backstack.

Comment: still not getting right. is there anyway to CLEAR_TOP for MainActivity and call another activity right there without going back to MainActivity?

Comment: You said - `"i need to get back to main activity from each activity"`. I said - you can call the `MainActivity` from any activity by just using the above code and this is what you want.

Comment: but whenever i use above code, screen goes blank for a second while launching any activity.